# Prestashop module link redirects to Admin dashboard in production server

Tags: nginx, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I developed a Prestashop module form my customer. I migrated the changes to the production server and I found out that if I access the controller url in production it redirects to the Admin Dashboard (or login screen if not logged in), but in local server it executes the code.

```
// working -> http://example.test/module/mymodule/mycontroller
// not working -> https://example.com/module/mymodule/mycontroller
 public function postProcess()
    {
        parent::postProcess();

        if (Tools::getIsset('request-budget-form')) {
            $this->requestBudget();

            $this->success[] = 'lorem ipsum';
            $this->redirectWithNotifications('/');
        }

        die('this line is printed in local, but the controller is never executed in production. its redirecting to admin dashboard instead.');
        Tools::redirect('/');
    }
```

I added the quotation form to the `cart-detailed-actions.tpl` template.

```
{block name='cart_detailed_actions'}
    <div class="checkout cart-detailed-actions card-block">
        {if $cart.minimalPurchaseRequired}
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                {$cart.minimalPurchaseRequired}
            </div>
            <div class="text-sm-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" disabled>{l s='Proceed to checkout' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}</button>
            </div>
        {elseif empty($cart.products) }
            <div class="text-sm-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled" disabled>{l s='Proceed to checkout' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}</button>
            </div>
        {else}
            <div class="text-sm-center">
                {if $requires_budget}
                <form action="{$link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'mycontroller', [], true)|escape:'html'}" method="post">
                        {if ! $customer.is_logged}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="budget-nom" style="width: 100%;text-align: left;">{l s='Nombre' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}</label>
                                <input id="budget-nom" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="budget-email" style="width: 100%;text-align: left;">{l s='Email' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}</label>
                                <input id="budget-email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                        {/if}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="budget-comments" style="width: 100%;text-align: left;">{l s='Comments' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" id="budget-comments" minlength="10" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" name="request-budget-form" class="btn btn-primary">
                            {l s='Ask for a quotation' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
                        </button>
                    </form>
                {else}
                <a href="{$urls.pages.order}" class="btn btn-primary">{l s='Proceed to checkout' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}</a>
                {hook h='displayExpressCheckout'}
                {/if}
            </div>
        {/if}
    </div>
{/block}
```

Comment: Try to clear cache

Comment: Cleared the caché at the admin panel, manually deleted cache files, tried incognito mode in the browser... Still making the redirect.

Comment: It's an admin controller? you should add code for the tpl file so we can debug better

Comment: No, its a front controller. `mymodule/controllers/front/mycontroller.php`. I edited the post to add the tpl file.

Comment: did you tried to clear cookies also try to put parent::postProcess(); at the end of the function

Comment: try to activate/disable friendly URLs to regenerate the htacess file